# How to get Emacs Live to recognize Hoplon (hl)?

Tags: emacs, clojurescript, hoplon

Does anyone know how I can get Emacs Live to recognize Hoplon (hl)? These hl files should be treated as a clojurescript file.

Answer (score 2):

If you use both HTML and s-expression syntax you may want to use the `.cljs.hl` and `.html.hl` extensions to help emacs differentiate between them. So you may want something like:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html\\.hl\\'" . html-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.cljs\\.hl\\'" . clojure-mode))
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `web-mode` instead of `html-mode`?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comment(s),

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.hl" . clojurescript-mode))
```

Should do the trick.